# Why is the mPDF WriteHTML text coming over the header and overflowing to the footer section?

Tags: php, mpdf

Why are contents inside the WriteHTML part overlapping with the header and footer section?
[image]

My code is as follows:

```
<?PHP
  require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

  // Define the Header/Footer before writing anything so they appear on the first page
  $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('
  <div style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold; background-color: coral;">
    My document
    <be>
    Go to HELL !
    <hr>
  </div>');

  $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('
  <table width="100%" style="background-color: coral;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Another Section</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Another Section</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="33%">{DATE j-m-Y}</td>
    <td width="33%" align="center">{PAGENO}/{nbpg}</td>
    <td width="33%" style="text-align: right;">My document</td>
  </tr>
  </table>');

  $mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello 
  World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello 
  World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello 
  World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello 
  World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello 
  World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello 
  World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello 
  World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello 
  World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello 
  World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello World<br>Hello 
  World<br>Hello World');

  $mpdf->Output();
?>
```

I want the "Hello World" text to reside inside the white portion that lies between the header and the footer, despite of the header's and footer's height.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation about margins](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/headers-top-margins.html) it says "If you specify a header that extends further down the page than the margin-top, then the header and main text will overlap.".

So I would just **modify the document margins** until you get what you desire.

I also noticed that some *mPDF* variables can be used to change the behavior of margins. Typically [setAutoTopMargin](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-variables/setautotopmargin.html) can be set to `pad` or `stretch` so that the top margin gets automatically changed if the header is to big.

Comment: ok, but how do you suggest I do that, I'm not that good with mPDF ?

Comment: @SumantBag Glad it helped you! I saw that you applied the margins on your page creation just below ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$mpdf->AddPage('P','','','','',15,15,30,30,10,10);
```

This single line solved my problem.

Comment: It would be good to add a comment explaining why it worked, explaining that it is due to the values of the page margins. This could help someone having the same problem as you ;-)